# selecting correct from number when sending sms with alphanumeric sender id

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm using twilio API for sending sms to my customers.

suppose I have 2 phone numbers in twilio
(US and AUS ).
I want to use from number based on my customers location.

if the customers is from US, then I send sms via US number, or
if the customers is from Australia , then I send sms via AUS number.

I know this is possible via API, by changing the "from" parameter value.

but my question is, If I need to use Alphanumeric as my sender Id ( for example my company name)
how can I do this by keeping the same logic ( from US > to US , from AUS to AUS)

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for here is a [Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services). Messaging Services have a couple of useful features for you here.

You can [connect an alphanumeric sender ID to your Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#alpha-sender) and Twilio will attempt to use that sender ID in countries that support it. There is also [geomatching](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#country-code-geomatch), so when you use a number to send a message through the service, or when it falls back to a number instead of an alphanumeric sender ID, it picks the nearest country to the recipient.

So, if you have an alphanumeric sender ID and a US number in your Messaging Service and send a message to a US number it will use the US number.